# Inheritance and Type Difference

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an overall axisModel that is extended by subtypes of axes. The problem is that the abstract methods that this being implemented will be a date in one class and a double in the other. The only solution I've been able to come up with is to make them generics and make assumptions when I instantiate these classes. Is there a more elegant solution? Below is some sample code to show what I'm trying to do.

```
public class abstract axisModel {
 abstract double method();
}

public class priceAxisModel extend axisModel {
 public double method() {
  //do stuff
 }
}

public class dateAxisModel extend axisModel {
 public date method() {
  //do stuff
 }
}
```

Comment: Generics would do what you're looking for, but I would think that if you need the same method to return two completely different types, then you really ought to have two different methods.

Comment: It is not usually recommended to use camelCase for class name.

Comment: It was just out of quick typing. I was writing it in the editor itself. Must of just alluded me. Thanks for the heads up though :)

Comment: I want to clarify my earlier comment: If you have other methods that accept parameters and/or return values of type T, then *absolutely* use generics, but if it's just one method, generics might be overkill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted to use generics will be a good solution in this situation. For example:

```
public class abstract AxisModel<T> {
 abstract T method();
}

public class PriceAxisModel extend AxisModel<Double> {
 public Double method() {
  //do stuff
 }
}

public class DateAxisModel extend AxisModel<Date> {
 public Date method() {
  //do stuff
 }
}
```

As for me, this code looks quite elegant.